# display child div attribute on click

Tags: jquery, html

This is a basic jQuery question no doubt, but I have an HTML div cluster like so:

```
<div class="sunti_contain" ng-repeat="sunti in suntis track by $index">
                <div class="individual_sunti">
                    <!--needs a unique div#id via angularz-->
                    <div class="sunti_content">{{sunti.content || 'content loading...'}}</div>
                    <div class="sunti_tags">{{sunti.tags || 'tags'}}</div>
                    <div class="sunti_author">{{sunti.author || 'author-placeholder'}}</div>
                    <div class="sunti_shortid">{{sunti.shortid}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

(the {{ }} are angular fill-ins, but they don't matter for this question)

On a click event on the parent element *.individual_sunti* , I want write out the child element *sunti_shortid* value to the console.

So far I have:

```
$('.individual_sunti').click(function() {
        console.log('caught a click on ' + $(this));
}
```

But I don't know what to add to $(this) to refer to the child element called *.sunti_shortid*

Something naieve like

```
    console.log('caught a click on ' + $(this > '.sunti_shortid'));
```

does not work

Comment: $(this).find('.sunti_shortid');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.find()`:

```
$(this).find('div.sunti_shortid');
```

or `.children()`:

```
$(this).children('div.sunti_shortid');
```

The difference being that `.children()` only checks (wait for it...) children elements (i.e. one level down), while `.find()` searches all descendants.

Comment: You know, your answer is totally correct for this question.  I am using angular and it turns out that jquery and angular don't really play well together.  To the point that any bound variables from your angular controller need functions that weave into and out of your angular controller javascript.  So although this is not the solution I used, I accept you answer.

Answer (score 0):

For getting a child element use the find() method enclosing what element you need to find using a class or id attribute.

```
$('.individual_sunti').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('.sunti_shortid'));
}
```